# Reading artifacts from a maven repository

Tags: java, maven, aether

I'm kinda new to maven and was wondering if anyone knew how to get all the artifacts from a repo. I was looking into using the aether library but I'm not exactly sure if its possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you like to get all artifacts, cause that pretty much...In Maven Central there are about 600 G...

Answer (score 0):

Open up a browser window and put the Repo URL in the address bar. You will have the entire list of libs there.